# Correct way to build a validator that depends on previously submitted nodes?

Tags: 7, forms

I'm developing a booking system using the Forms API and a node type to store a booking in.

hook_form_validate is used to make sure that no overlapping bookings are created - this  means if existing booking A is from 9:00 to 12:00, and a new booking is submitted for 11:00 to 13:00, validation fails because the range 11:00 to 12:00 overlaps. My validator looks like:

```
function custom_booking_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  $thing_to_book = $form_state['values']['field_thing_to_book'];
  $time = $form_state['values']['field_time'];

  if(overlapping_booking_exists($booking, $thing_to_book)) {
    form_set_error('Looks like this time is already taken.');
  }
}
```

This works as expected when two different users pick the same time in the form, customer A clicks submit and then customer B clicks submit. User B will get the form error.

However, if customer A clicks submit twice("submit spam"), the validation of the second submissions will incorrectly pass because Drupal seems to execute the validate/submit functions in this order:

```
(pseudocode)
validate_form_submission(first submission);
validate_form_submission(second submission);
handle_form_submission(first submission);
handle_form_submission(second submission);
```

While for my logic to work properly, it needs to be:

```
(pseudocode)
validate_form_submission(first submission);
handle_form_submission(first submission);
validate_form_submission(second submission);
handle_form_submission(second submission);
```

I have found two workarounds that are both unsuitable:

- Hide the submit button with JS after clicking it to prevent a second click. This is not suitable because this is a live site, and therefore mischief such as
- Put redundant validation logic in the hook_form_submit function. This is not really an option because the clients' requirements are quite complicated and change regularly,

How do we solve this "the drupal way"?